# Extracting a substring from between characters using formula

Tags: excel, formula

I have rows with the following data

```
Delivered - signed for by XXX - on 05 Aug 2019 at 15:06
```

I want to extract the date only from this. I have been using the word "on" and "at" as my search words as these only appear once in each line before and after the date.

Every time I am trying to do this I return both the date and the time where I only need 05 Aug 2019.

The formula I am using is this.

```
=MID(A2,SEARCH("on",A2)+2,SEARCH("at",A2)-1)
```

I noticed that when I had the first part as +1, although I was searching for the word "on" the formula would result with giving me the "n" as well.

I have also tried

```
=MID(LEFT(A4,FIND("on",A4)+2),FIND("at",A4)-1,LEN(A4))
```

However, this just leaves me with a blank cell.

I also then have the issue off if the name of the person who signed has ON in there name for example Jason. The formula would pick up the "on" from the name before the "on" before the date.

Any help is appreciated and no doubt it is stirring me in the face.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SEARCH returns the position of the *first* character of your search text, so you need to adjust that by the length of the search text. Also, the third argument to MID is the number of characters to return, not the position to stop at, so you need to subtract the result of the first search from the second. Finally, I'd search for " on " and " at " to eliminate the name issue, and TRIM the result for safety:

```
=TRIM(MID(A2,SEARCH(" on ",A2)+4,SEARCH(" at ",A2)-SEARCH(" on ",A2)-4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
=LEFT(MID(A2,FIND("on ",A2)+3,99),FIND("at",MID(A2,FIND("on ",A2)+3,99))-2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=MID(A2,SEARCH("on ",A2)+3,SEARCH(" at ",A2)-SEARCH("on ",A2)-3)
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

If the format of your dates are the same ("dd mmm yyyy") on all entries, you could try:

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH(" on ",A1)+4,11)
```

And if you want a datevalue instead of text you just put `DATEVALUE` in front:

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,SEARCH(" on ",A1)+4,11))
```

Answer (score 1):

C6 = Delivered - signed for by XXX - on 05 Aug 2019 at 15:06

=LEFT(RIGHT(C6;20);11)